# Location to proxy_pass is not working, where the bug?

Tags: nginx

It is a simple webservce at port 3000 redirect by NGINX `location` directive, but need to add an MIME Accept before `proxy_pass`. I usimg UBUNTU 18 LTS server, and do, step-by-step:

1. `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/myServce`
2. `sudo nginx -t`
3. `sudo service nginx restart`

Something more? Seems the problem is on *myServce NGINX script*, that I copy below.

---

### Configs

The NGINX configuration at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myServce`,

```
server {
    root /var/www/myServce/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name sub1.myServce.etc;

    location ~ ^/_sql.csv/(.*) {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;  # suppose sub1.myServce.etc
      proxy_set_header Accept 'text/csv';
      proxy_pass  http://localhost:3000/$1; # same when sub1.myServce.etc
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
    }
}
```

### Tests

Reference-tests, all are working fine:

1. `curl  http://myServce.etc:3000/`
2. `curl  http://myServce.etc:3000/t?limit=10`

To emulate the expected results on test2, used `curl --header "Accept: text/csv" http://myServce.etc:3000/t?limit=10` and also working fine.

The analogous tests on the implemented redirector, all are bug:

1. `curl  http://myServce.etc/_sql.csv/` returns  502 Bad Gateway.
2. `curl  http://myServce.etc/_sql.csv/t?limit=10` returns  502 Bad Gateway.

Comment: PS: in real-life the webservice of the port 3000 endpoint is discussed at https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/issues/1418

Comment: `http://myServce.etc/_sql.csv/` doesn't match `^/_sql.csv/(.+)`. Try `^/_sql.csv/(.*)` instead

Comment: @PavelLint, oops, yes (!) thanks for this first collaboration. I will edit here and at my server.... But see tests, same HTTP-error 502 on `/_sql.csv/etc` requests.

Comment: also make sure your proxy is listening on localhost:3000. Maybe it only listens to myService.etc:3000

Comment: Hi @PavelLint, I edited to check if it is fine,  I am supposing that subdomains are used on `Host $host` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that is working,

```
location /_sql.csv/ {
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   # add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$request_filename.csv"';
   proxy_set_header Accept 'text/csv';
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
```

it bypass all string after `_sql.csv`.

---

The solution created other [open problem on filename extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59112021/287948).